# [VB.NET]Upnp/udp hole punch chat program tcp/udp sockets

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcp, udp, p2p

I am trying to make a very simple client server chat programm. Only i need is a program that send a tcp/udp or socket message to the server and the server to the client, and multi client/server application if possible. But the problem is that it is only possible with LAN applications. I made a reasearch and there are three ways to solve it: manually, adding the port forwarding to the router. Or, upnp way, as p2p. Or even, something called udp hole punch that also works. I only need someone that could give me an done sample of a chat program of some of the two last situations. I know that there are many people thar have it, but, unfortunely, no one gives an example of code. Only LAN, but no one have already done some opensource of what i am trying to find. Tnx. Only a simple application with that already done, please. Nothing very big.

Comment: Does you have some vb.net code example of that or some other thing that could work, please?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, UPNP and NAT-PMP can work. But there are no simple application as you want, these source codes are relatively simple but you still need to know something about the protocol and write code foryouself.

The NAT-PMP protocol : https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent/blob/RC_1_2/src/natpmp.cpp

The UPNP protocol : https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent/blob/RC_1_2/src/upnp.cpp